# i can't render my project

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: screenshot]I've created my first 3d object (a donut) and when I tried to render it, it worked, took me like 20 mins and then I've added a "image as background" and tried rendering and I couldn't render it at all, it just gets stuck at a point and I can't even use my mouse, only way I can use my pc is to force restart.
please help

PC specifications

AMD Ryzen 3 1300x quad core processor

Nvidia GTX 1050ti 4 gb

24 gb ram ddr4 1600MHz

windows 10 pro N latest build

Blender version 2.83.5

no ssd

and any tips to make my blender run smoothly?

[image: render settings]

[image: my donut]

[image: more settings]

[image: the error]

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots. The current ones are quite hard to see. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, while rendering i can't use my PC, i have to restart my pc to use it, so, i can't take screenshots

Comment: How many times did you subdivide the donut?

Comment: Hey, i added 2 subdivision surface to the donut and 1 to the icing, btw i added the screenshot.

Comment: Maybe try rendering using only your GPU (uncheck the CPU in the preferences). I made the experience that, when Blender uses the CPU and does heavy work, the PC can freeze (because it has a CPU usage of 100%).

Comment: hey thanks, i fixed the issue by adding a decimate modifier to donut and icing, now i can render about 20 frames in 20 mins lol